# Getting "Undo log record is too big" error from MySQL when updating json field

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-json

Running MySQL 8.0.32 on Ububntu 20.04, I get above error randomly (?) for this query:

```
update `user` set `user`.`influencers` = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(influencers, '$', ?), `user`.`row_timestamp` =`user`.`row_timestamp` where (`user`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and not (? member of(influencers)))
```

I could only find one page about this error and it mentions this happens when you update. mediumtext field of a very specific size. But my field is not mediumtext.

Any idea about this and how to fix/avoid it or any workaround?

Comment: This usually happens when you're doing too much in a single transaction. The error is telling you it's running out of room to store the information needed to roll back the transaction if something fails. You can work around it by breaking your very large update into smaller chunks.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite. Actually, this is the minified version of an original large query which was using around 100 parameters. I guess the issue is with the `user id in (?, ... ?)` part. Right?

Comment: I would store the multi-value attribute as multiple rows in a related table, not as JSON.

Comment: This still happens even with one parameter `user id in (?)`